# How to test non-awaited async function calls in mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I want to write a mocha test suite for a reservation service that calls a postReservation service which runs asynchronously? How to test if the postReservation service was called?

```
async function bookReservation(...){
    await bookReservationForUser(...);
    postReservation(...);
}
```

```
async function postReservation(...){
    await DoSomeThing();
    await DoSomeOtherThing();
}
```

It there a better way to do than this:

Mocha test suite:

```
describe('Test Suite', function(){
    it('TC', async function(){
         await bookReservation(...);
         await(wait(2000));
         expect(postReservation.toBeCalled).true;
    })
});
```

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with your test. It mostly comes down to implementation as it differs depending on your assertion library and how you structure your code.

Essentially, you can watch `postReservation` by using either a `spy` or `stub`. If you're not concerned with a return value then a spy works great.

In the below test example using your code, each module has a short delay from `wait`. The tests calls `Module C` which calls `Module B` and `Module A`. The test checks that `B` / `A` were both called via `C`.

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/express-mocha-chai-sinon-spies-esm-sv3kvm) to try the test.

**index.test.js**

```
import sinon from "sinon";
import referee from "@sinonjs/referee";
import moduleC from "./moduleC.js";
import moduleB from "./moduleB.js";
import moduleA from "./moduleA.js";

const assert = referee.assert;

describe("book a reservation", () => {
  it("both spys should be called", async () => {
    const spy1 = sinon.spy(moduleA, "postReservation");
    const spy2 = sinon.spy(moduleB, "bookReservationForUser");
    await moduleC.bookReservation();
    assert(spy1.called);
    assert(spy2.called);
  }).timeout(15000);
});
```

**wait.js**

```
const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
export default wait;
```

**moduleA.js**

```
import wait from "./wait.js";

async function postReservation() {
  console.log("--- postReservation ---");
  return wait(1500);
}

export default {
  postReservation,
};
```

**moduleB.js**

```
import wait from "./wait.js";

async function bookReservationForUser() {
  console.log("--- bookReservationForUser ---");
  return wait(1500);
}

export default {
  bookReservationForUser,
};
```

**moduleC.js**

```
import wait from "./wait.js";
import moduleB from "./moduleB.js";
import moduleA from "./moduleA.js";

async function bookReservation() {
  console.log("--- bookReservation ---");
  await wait(2000);
  await moduleB.bookReservationForUser();
  return moduleA.postReservation();
}

export default {
  bookReservation,
};
```

[image: Test results:]

If you're working with CJS instead of ESM, then how you structure your modules, instantiate them and import them in your tests changes slightly. Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/express-mocha-chai-sinon-spies-cjs-g7iywh) for CJS modules.